# Getting an empty jpg file, when try to Download an image

Tags: python, urllib

I have been trying to download an image from website (no username and password required) but every time I am getting an empty file. I have used conventional urllib .retrieve and requests methodologies but getting the same result. One thing more is that if I try to open the same image manually by copy pasting the URL after 15-20 min then that image itself does not open. I am assuming that some sort of session handling is required in this case . Below is my code which returns me empty image.

```
import os
import urllib

def savePic(url):
    uri="C:\Python27\Scripts\Photosurl2.jpg" 
    if url!="":
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, uri)

savePic("http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?ImageView&ImageID=491410290&Desc=Lookback+from+final+rest&Title=Scene+Photos+-+image1&Version=1&Extend=jpg")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The URL itself doesn't show any photos here!

Comment: This url is invalid to get a image!

Comment: @ Gabriel  and @ Jahangir  .You can try the below steps to see the actual image and then copy that URL and try to open it. It will open in the first instance but after 15-20 min if you try to open it again u will see what you are currently seeing by copying and pasting the URL. One thing more the Image differs by ImageID and Desc . Following are steps: 1. http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=491015675 .ID can differ but steps remain the same) 2. On left side under NASS case open crash overview, continue in next post –

Comment: Under Crash Overview (+ sign) you will see scene photos click on the + sign again there you will see Vehicle 1 ( and Vehicle 2) click on that link. These are the images which I need to download . Click on any of the images to get the URL it will be same as above (except the ImageID and Desc). You can open this URL in new window to check it but after 15-20 min if you try to open the same link you will see the image which you are currently seeing.   I am again providing the link mentioned in step1:     http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=491015675

Answer (score 0):

When you try to implement some HTTP code in Python do not forget to validate that you can use `curl` or `wget` to perform these HTTP requests. This will save you a lot of time trying to debug a problem that is not in your code.

The also have very good verbose modes which will give you some hints regarding what you are missing.

Also, most senior Python developers are using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library instead of the urllib ones.

PS. Requests library is easier to use than urllib.